# How do I create a trigger to update a column from other columns' data in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to updated a Balance_Due column with the contents of Invoice_Total, Payment_Total, and Credit_Total. The Three_Numbers function calculates the Balance_Due.

I've spent a large chunk of time on this and can't figure out the correct syntax. Here is what I have so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BALANCE_DUE_BEFORE 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON INVOICES6
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE INVOICES6
  SET BALANCE_DUE = THREE_NUMBERS(INVOICE_TOTAL, CREDIT_TOTAL, PAYMENT_TOTAL);
END;
```

Comment: where have you defined `THREE_NUMBERS` function ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu My teacher has us use Oracle's SQL Developer software. I created the function and it is stored in the functions folder of the same database connection I am creating the trigger. Why do you ask? Does the code look correct to you?